# How to set min width or bigger in XAML of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin.forms

I like to know how I can set the width of an element to be minimum of X or bigger.

For example, consider the XAML below (contains only the markup for the text with blue background in the screenshot for simplicity):

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0"
  ColumnSpacing="0">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Label
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Margin="10,0,10,0"
    Text="Lorem ipsum"
    BackgroundColor="Aqua"
    FontSize="24"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
    WidthRequest="{OnIdiom Default=400, Phone=300}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want the text element with blue background to take the space that it has but if the text is bigger, I want the width to expand.

[image]

But right now for bigger texts it looks like this:
[image]

Whereas, I want to make it somehow look like this without (while still taking the min width in the first screenshot):
[image]

Comment: [`MinimumWidthRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.minimumwidthrequest?view=xamarin-forms)?

Comment: MinimumWidthRequest is actually very badly named property and doesn't really do what I want. According to one Xamarin team members: Most people interpret it to mean "The minimum size the control can ever be and no smaller ever" where the actual intent of the property is "the smallest size the control can be squished to when the desired size cannot be met". Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84885/obsolete-minimum-width-height-request

Comment: use row definition to restrict as you are already using grid

Comment: Are there any new updates?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider using [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) to achieve this:

for example:

for android:

create a **MiniWidthLabel**

```
public class MiniWidthLabel :Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MinWidthProperty =BindableProperty.Create("MinWidth", typeof(int), typeof(MiniWidthLabel), null);
    public int MinWidth
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinWidthProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

create a **MinWidthLableRenderer** in your Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MiniWidthLabel), typeof(MinWidthLableRenderer))]
namespace your namepace
{
 class MinWidthLableRenderer:LabelRenderer
  {

    public MinWidthLableRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetMinWidth(((MiniWidthLabel)Element).MinWidth);

    }
  }
}
```

then use in your page.xaml:

```
<local:MiniWidthLabel Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="" BackgroundColor="Aqua"  MinWidth="200" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Start"></local:MiniWidthLabel>
```